# Trouble with matplotlib fill_between() and > symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use the fill_between() function from matplotlib for a graph I'm making. I used the exact code from the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py) but when I use it I get the following error:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
y1 = sns.lineplot('game_seconds_remaining', 'home_wp', data=vb, color='#4F2683',linewidth=2)
y2 = sns.lineplot('game_seconds_remaining', 'away_wp', data=vb, color='#FB4F14',linewidth=2)

x = plt.axhline(y=.50, color='white', alpha=0.7)

ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, where=(y1 > x), color='C0', alpha=0.3, interpolate=True)

Output: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'AxesSubplot' and 'AxesSubplot'
```

Why is this not working for me yet it works on the documentation? What I want to do is shade any area that dips below the horizontal line (x) and above it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that you are not using it the way it is used in the documentation. In the docs, numbers are compared with numbers. You try to compare plots with plots.

Comment: Ah, I see @warped. Is there a way I can get an array of the values that consist of my plot, like the documentation has? Edit: I could just assign the dataframe column as a variable. Let me try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dummy data:

```
# dummy dataframe
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 100)

df= pd.DataFrame({
    'a': x,
    'b': np.cos(x),
    'c': np.sin(x), 
})

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
sns.lineplot('a', 'b', data=df, ax=ax, label='b')
sns.lineplot('a', 'c', data=df, ax=ax, label='c')

ax.fill_between(df['a'], 0.5, df['b'], where=df['b']>.5)
ax.fill_between(df['a'], 0.5, df['c'], where=df['c']>.5)
```

[image]

Comment: This is helpful, but what I'm trying to do exactly (which I originally explained poorly), is shade when the line graph is above my hline in the original code. So for example, in your plot, I would want to shade the area where lines b and c are greater than .50 (if you were to make an hline there) ie. plt.axhline(y=.50, color='black')

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted. It looks great, however, there are two big chunks that python didn't shade for some reason. They are rectangles that go from the horizontal line to the line graph... odd. Regardless, your answer helped a ton and I marked as correct and upvoted. I'm just curious to see if there is a fix for this glitch and to get these rectangles to fill?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. can you upload an image?

Comment: I messaged you.